# Typed text is not displaying in console while using conio.h

Tags: c, input, console, conio

I am using conio.h in my project to display the game board. I need to read input from a user. In generally works, but it behaves like linux passwords (input is passed to a variable but not displayed in the console). I need to see the input being entered (as in the image below). The `getch()` method from conio.h also doesn't show input.

[image: expected behavior]

```
char text[16];
scanf("%s", text);
printf("text: %s", text);
```

sample code (only shows "a" in (5, 5), typed text is not visible)

```
Conio2_Init();
gotoxy(5, 5);
putch('a');
gotoxy(1, 1);
char a[16];
scanf("%s", a);
```

Is there a way to use conio.h and read user input explicitly?

Comment: Instead of `getch()` you could try `getche()` (with echo).